# Reference request: log Fano varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, toric-varieties, fano-varieties

I need a reference for a proof of the following fact: let $X$ be a toric variety then $X$ is log Fano.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What if $X$ is not projective?

Comment: It's really easy in the projective case (as Piotr points out, what do you mean in the non-projective case?).  Let $A> 0$ be an ample Cartier toric divisor.  Consider $-K_X - e A$ for some small $e$.  This is a divisor with the same support as $-K_X = \text{Supp}(K_X)$ but with all coefficients in $(0, 1)$.  Set $\Delta = -K_X - eA$.  Then we see that $-K_X-\Delta$ is ample.  Also, we see that $(X, \Delta)$ is KLT because $(X, \lceil \Delta \rceil)$ is LC (since $\lceil \Delta \rceil = -K_X$ and $K_X-K_X = 0$).  Anyway, did you check out Cox-Little-Schenck?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Of course I meant projective toric variety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the detailed argument. First one has to prove the following.

**Lemma 1**
Let $D = \sum_i d_iD_i$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor on a normal projective variety $X$ such that $d_i < 1$ and the pair $(X,\lceil D \rceil)$ is lc. Then $(X,D)$ is klt.

*proof)* Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a log resolution of the pair $(X,\lceil D \rceil)$. We have 
$$K_Y = f^{*}K_X+\sum_ia_iE_i$$
and
$${\lceil \widetilde{D} \rceil} = f^*\lceil D \rceil-\sum_ib_i E_i$$
where $\lceil \widetilde{D} \rceil$ is the strict transform of $\lceil D \rceil$. Therefore, 
$$K_Y = f^{*}(K_X+\lceil D \rceil)+\sum_i(a_i-b_i)-\lceil \widetilde{D} \rceil$$
and since $(X,\lceil D \rceil)$ is lc we have $a_i-b_1\geq -1$. On the other hand 
$$\widetilde{D} = f^{*}D-\sum_it_iE_i$$
with $t_i<b_i$ because $d_i<1$ for any $i$. This yields $a_i-t_i > a_i-b_i\geq -1$, and the pair $(X,D)$ is klt.

Now you have:

**Proposition**
Let $X$ be a projective toric variety. Then $X$ is log Fano.

*proof)* Let $D_1^X,...,D_r^X$ be the irreducible toric invariant divisors on $X$. Then we have $K_X = -\sum_iD_i^X$, see \cite{Ful}. Now, let $A = \sum_ia_iD_i^X$ be an ample toric invariant divisor, and $\epsilon$ a rational number $0<\epsilon \ll 1$. Therefore
$$-K_X-\epsilon A = \sum_i(1-\epsilon a_i)D_i^X$$
with $1-\epsilon a_i < 1$. The divisor $D = \sum_i(1-\epsilon a_i)D_i^X$ is such that $\epsilon A = -K_X -D$ is ample. Note that $\lceil D\rceil \sim -K_X$. Let $f:Y\rightarrow X$ be a toric log resolution of $(X,\lceil D\rceil)$, and let $D_1^Y,...,D_h^Y$ be the invariant toric divisors on $Y$. We have
$$K_Y = f^*(K_X+\lceil D\rceil)+\sum a_iE_i-\lceil \widetilde{D}\rceil = \sum a_iE_i-\lceil \widetilde{D}\rceil$$
because $\lceil D\rceil \sim -K_X$. On the other hand $K_Y = -\sum_iD_i^Y$ yields
$$K_Y = \sum a_iE_i-\lceil \widetilde{D}\rceil = -\sum_iD_i^Y.$$
This forces $a_i = -1$ for any $i$. Therefore, the pair $(X,\lceil D\rceil)$ is lc. To conclude it is enough to apply Lemma 1.